# How can I avoid losing my Cypher Query?

Tags: browser, neo4j, directory, cypher, graph-databases

I have a neo4j database and I use neo4j server and the browser UI (localhost:7474/browser).
If I use CCleaner to delete temporary files, I lose every query and stylesheet I saved.

I use Google Chrome. Is there a folder in Chrome path where I could find a file like “*neo4j.data*” that contains the whole information about my database?
I would copy this file into another folder, use CCleaner and then re-copy the settings. 
In this way I shouldn't miss nothing!

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Neo4j stores its settings in local storage of your browser. Perhaps CCleaner can exempt certain storage entries. Otherwise you have to copy those out and add them back later.

Comment: I take your advice and I find the settings in local storage of Chrome.Thank you very much Michael!